# I have an HTML Page, but need to output my java output into it. Is that possible?

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to make my java code output appear in a html footer of a website that I have made. Is that possible?

I was thinking of using String Builder in order to do

System.out.println("Html code here");

Does that seem right?

Comment: `System.out.println` wont work. You need to write in the output stream of the http response.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Some browsers stopped supporting the standard Java plugin so check compatibility

Answer (score 0):

To use Java to on a website you need to utilize [Java Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) or JavaServer Pages ([JSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)). These special java programs are run inside a servlet container which runs in a suitable web server. Tomcat and Glassfish are popular options. This type of Java programming falls under the category of [Java Enterprise Edition (Java EE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html).

Please look for a tutorial covering these topics. One such tutorial is the [Java EE 7 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/).

For a servlet you extend the class `HttpServlet` and then override the `doGet` or `doPost` method to generate the desired output.

Here is an extremely basic example of a servlet that could process an HTTP GET request, showing how you would write the html code using the response object instead of `System.out.println()`.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.getWriter().write("html code here");
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

System.out is not useful,you'd got outputstream from response.

and then,HTML is pure static page,it's no relationship with java.

So,if you want your java output appear in a HTML page,I think,you need ajax.